# How can I draw Rounded Rectangles around my textfields and buttons like Foursquare app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitextfield

How can I draw a background behind all my buttons and textfields like on the Foursquare iPhone app?  See where it says "Share with..."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve rounded corners on any view by changing the `cornerRadius` property of the view's backing CALayer. To access these properties, you will have to link against the QuartzCore framework.

Then you can change the corner radius like this:

```
textFieldBackgroundView.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
```

Just make sure to add `<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` to your project and `#import` it.

Comment: But what if I have a textField and label and I want both surrounded by the same Rounded Rect?  Like "Favorite color?  UITextField"

Comment: Then add textField and label as subviews of the view with the rounded corners.